# Google Vision not returning Vertices

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-vision, google-apis-explorer

I am sending images through the Google Vision OCR API to obtain a text layer of the document, I have have no issues with this previously and have run it through at least a thousand times in testing. I recently delivered a POC to someone and they were reporting errors with not getting back valid text layers.

I looked and inside my JSON return I am not getting Vertices back from Google.

Here is my Request:

```
{
"requests": [
{
    "inputConfig': {
    "content': [tiff byte stream to string goes here],
    "mimeType': 'image/tiff"
    },
    'pages': [
    1
    ],
    'features': [
    {
        'type': 'DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION'
    }
    ]
}
]
}
```

Here is a very small sample of what I am getting back

```
{
  "property": {
    "detectedLanguages": [
      {
        "languageCode": "en"
      }
    ]
  },
  "boundingBox": {
    "vertices": [
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {}
    ]
  },
  "text": "1",
  "confidence": 0.99
},
{
  "property": {
    "detectedLanguages": [
      {
        "languageCode": "en"
      }
    ]
  },
  "boundingBox": {
    "vertices": [
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {}
    ]
  },
  "text": "4",
  "confidence": 0.97
},
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps this problem is a bug since this is not the expected behavior. I encourage you to create a public issue for GCP support (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=1161261). Please, when filling the information, add your StackOverflow case's link.

Comment: Opened a defect with google, fix is pending according to them. This was not a code issue, thanks for input all!

Answer (score 1):

Vision API uses [Protocol Buffers v3](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/proto3)

> An unset primitive field has a language-defined default value.

If the X or Y value is unset, it means it is 0.

Comment: Up until this week this has been working, I do not believe that is my issue as no every value in the file is located at X and Y 0.